# ¿Por qué al hacer alguna operación el resultado es un número basura?

Tags: c, codeblocks

Ya había hecho algo parecido antes, apenas estoy comenzando en la programación, y si funciono correctamente, quise volver a hacer otro programa de suma similar pero el resultado me da un numero basura como 6356740

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a=0, b=0, suma=0;
   printf("Introduce un numero profavor: ");
   scanf("%d",&a);
   scanf("%d",&b);
   suma=b+a;
   printf("%d",&suma);
   getch();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque cuando quieres imprimir en pantalla tienes `printf("%d",&suma)` y el '&' hace que imprimas la dirección de memoria del la variable no el valor como tal, para imprimir el valor debes escribir `printf("%d",suma)`